# Can you hide an element in a layout, such as a spinner, depending on an activity?

Tags: android, layout, spinner

I am working on my app which has 3 spinners in one view. Some of my activities will need to use 3 spinners, some 2, some 1, so I would like to hide them depending on the activity, if that is even possible. I am trying to do it like this so I can be as efficient as possible, but I have no idea if it is even possible.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Call `setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)` or `setVisibility(View.GONE)` on the `Spinners` as needed to hide them. `GONE` means totally gone; `INVISIBLE` means they still take up space but no pixels are drawn.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a View's method setVisibility: You can hide or show views using setVisibility(int visibility).

Where the argument can be INVISIBLE or GONE, depending on whether you want it to take up any space when it's invisible.