# Why does edittext with empty text still have some height?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I researched the attribute value wrap_content on another thread and found its function to be to "  force [the view] to expand only far enough to contain the values (or child controls) it contains. For controls -- like text boxes (TextView) or images (ImageView) -- this will wrap the text or image being shown."([What's the difference between fill_parent and wrap_content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432763/whats-the-difference-between-fill-parent-and-wrap-content))
Heres my code(for empty edittext

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Email"
        android:padding="5dp"/>
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       />

</LinearLayout>
```

And the resulting layout(selected one is the edit text) https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0UjK.jpg

My question is that because the edit text contains nothing(empty text), shouldnt wrap_ content force it to have no height?

Comment: The user needs to be able to type. If the `EditText` had no height, they couldn't. Hence, I would assume `EditText` enforces a minimum one-line height.

Comment: If you want to hide an element take a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480489/can-you-hide-an-element-in-a-layout-such-as-a-spinner-depending-on-an-activity

Comment: no i dont want to hide it. Im just curious why the thing still has height after wrap_content

Comment: comment one makes sense, didnt think of that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wrap_content` should be different ,once you make widgets by default wrap_content ,it will adjust the widget size  automatically for  all the screen such as small,medium and big screens.
But you have mention dp wise, all screen follows dp values only but it will not adjust automatically.

`fill_parent` and `match_parent` will stretch with their parent layout

Comment: And were is this answer to question please ? Why has empty EditText with wrap  content height ?  Any way to fix this ?

Comment: @Renetik I am not sure, try removing the cursor from edittext.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is another Android sdk "Feature Bug". There is android:minLines=".."  and it works but setting 0 is ignored for unknown reasons to me so it always stay as 1.